# Icono pause y play no aparecen video player

Tags: android, flutter, dart

No me aparece el icono al momento de tocar la pantalla para pausar y reproducir, el pausado y reproduccion al momento de tocar si funcionan correctamente pero no aparecen los iconos.

Mi código es el siguiente, le implementé el icono dentro del onTap para que apareciera cada vez que presiono la pantalla, ya que si lo pongo a fuera me genera errores.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? videoPlayerController!.pause()
                    : videoPlayerController!.play();
              });
              Icon(//bug icon dont show
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? Icons.pause
                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                size: 80,
              );
            },
            child: (videoPlayerController == null)
                ? const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : ((videoPlayerController!.value.isInitialized)
                    ? VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController!)
                    : const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Cargando Contenido....',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `Icon` lo estás colocando dentro del método `onTap: ()`, lo cual es incorrecto, el `InkWell` como la mayoría de Widgets tienen un atributo `child` , ahí es donde debes colocar el Widget que quieres mostrar:

```dart
InkWell(    
            child: 
              Icon(
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? Icons.pause
                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                size: 80,
             ),
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? videoPlayerController!.pause()
                    : videoPlayerController!.play();
              });
            },
```

Veo que estás usando el `child` pero para mostrar texto mientras el video se carga, para eso podrías usar `Stack`.

```dart
Stack (
  children: [

  // Aquí muestras el cargando (lo que tenías dentro de child, anteriormente)...
(videoPlayerController == null)
                ? const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : ((videoPlayerController!.value.isInitialized)
                    ? VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController!)
                    : const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Cargando Contenido....',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )))),
    

   // Tu botón delante del contenido
    InkWell(    
            child: 
              Icon(
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? Icons.pause
                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                size: 80,
             ),
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                    ? videoPlayerController!.pause()
                    : videoPlayerController!.play();
              });
            },
 ]
)
```

Comment: Gracias bro por la explicación y las correcciones, ya pude entender mi error, mil gracias :)